# How a application is launched from user tapping on AppIcon to application Launch iOS?(At OS level)

Tags: ios, iphone

Can anyone tell how the OS invoke the application in iOS.

User Taps an icon --> UIApplicationMain() function called --->Did finish launching called.

Is this the sequence? I tried to search but haven't got any clear explanation.

Comment: Look this: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html

Answer (score 1):

When your app is launched, it moves from the not running state to the active or background state, transitioning briefly through the inactive state. As part of the launch cycle, the system creates a process and main thread for your app and calls your app’s main function on that main thread. The default main function that comes with your Xcode project promptly hands control over to the UIKit framework, which does most of the work in initializing your app and preparing it to run.

Figure shows the sequence of events that occurs when an app is launched into the foreground, including the app delegate methods that are called.

[image]

For more Details look this: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html

Comment: can you tell me what happens when user taps an icon and before main() is called. How OS identifies which app to launch exactly?

Comment: @BabluJoshi This is the work of operating system and it identifies the app using its bundle identifier. We don't have any access to that level.

Comment: I want to know at kernel level what exactly happens.

Comment: The iOS kernel is the XNU kernel of Darwin. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS#Kernel

Then follow @ParthAdroja's answer.